# good design for a db that decreases resolution of accuracy after time

Tags: mysql, database-design, graph

I have something like 20,000 data points in a database and I want to display it on the google annotated graph. I think around 2000 points would be a good number to actually use the graph for, so I want to use averages instead of the real amount of data points I have.

This data counts the frequency of something a certain time. it would be like Table(frequency, datetime)

So for the first week I will have datetime have an interval of every 10 minutes, and frequency will be an average of all the frequencies of that time interval (of 10 minutes). Similarly, for the month after that I will I have a datetime interval of an hour etc.

I think this is something you can see on google finance too, after some time the resolution of the datapoints decreases even when you zoom in.

So what would be a good design for this? Is there already a tool that exists to do something like this?
I already thought of (though it might not be good) a giant table of all 20,000 points and several smaller tables that represent each time interval (1 week, 1 month etc) that are built through queries to the larger table and constantly updated and trimmed with new averages.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the raw data in the db in one table the. Have a second reprti g table which you use a script or query to populate from the raw table.  The transformation that populates the reporting table can group and average the buckets however you want.  The important thing Is to not transform your data on initial insert--keep all your raw data.  That way you can always rollback or rebuild if you mess something up.

ETL. Learn it. Love it. Live it.

Comment: Isn't that what I said in the last paragraph? Anyway I can see this being difficult for me. Change 20,000 to 1 million and still want the tables to be updated every 5-15 minutes.

Comment: Anyway good to know that my natural conclusion is the same as someone elses. Thank you for the answer.